# Sum of the values o each class is different to the number of samples sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, decision-tree, xgboost

The sum of the values of each class is different to the total number of samples in the node, could you explain it? In the image i have an example of this.

I have 337957 samples in the node and parallel i have [167542, 272872] of each class, but the sum of the elements in each class is different to the total of samples.

[image: example]

In another case i have the same problem this is the code and the image
[image: example2]

Comment: Do you have the data and the code that generated this graph ?

Comment: It is because Random Forest works with the duplicates generated using bootstrap sampling. Read more on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131893/random-forest-with-bootstrap-false-in-scikit-learn-python). You can try setting the `bootstrap=False`.

Comment: @vlemaistre i added the code right now, to be honest i am implementing a very simple decision tree.

Comment: @Vishal but, i am implementing a decision tree, it's the same problem?